# "ĉu" vi amas lin? -aŭ- "ke" vi amas lin?

Tags: word-usage

Duolingo: "Kiam vi diros al li, ĉu vi amas lin?"

(Vidu ĉe la Duolinga forumo: [eo→en](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/16202590), [en→eo](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/9452986).)

**Kial Duolingo uzas "ĉu" en la frazo, anstataŭ "ke"?** (Mi scias ke "ĉu" signifas "if/whether", sed mi pensas ke oni devas uzi "ke" en la frazo. Mi tradukas la frazon kun "ĉu" tielmaniere: "When will you tell him, if you love him (or not)"? Sed tradukas la frazon kun "ke" tielmaniere: "When will you tell him, that you love him?". Mi kredas ke la frazo, uzante "ke", estos pliklara ol diri tion kun "ĉu"; ĉu ne?

Comment: Dankon Sinjor(in)o @das-g pro la ligiloj.

Comment: Nedankinde! Dankon pro via interesa demando.

Answer (score 6):

La signifoj inter la du frazoj estas malsamaj:

> Kiam vi diros al li, ke vi amas lin?

La ‘vi’-persono amas lin kaj la demando estas, kiam tiu persono informas lin pri tio.

> Kiam vi diros al li, ĉu vi amas lin?

Ni ne scias, ĉu la ‘vi’-persono amas lin aŭ ne, kaj la demando estas, kiam tiu persono informas lin pri tio (ĉu ja amas aŭ ĉu ne amas).

---

La saman diferencon ni havas inter la anglaj frazoj.

Comment: Jes, Sinjor(in)o @Joffysloffy, mi mem skribis la signifojn de la frazoj, en mia demando. Mia demando estis alia.

Comment: Do kio estas via demando? En la ekzemploj de Duolingo, ili uzas _ĉu_ por la signifo de _whether_, kio bonas. Uzi _ke_ por la signifo de _whether_ estas simple malĝuste. Tion mi ekzemplas per la du frazoj. Vi demandas “ĉu unu frazo estas pli klara ol alia”, kaj mi montras, ke ne temas pri klareco, sed pri diferenco rilate signifon.

Comment: Ne, mi kredas ke uzi "ke" kaŭzas la frazon esti pliklara; ĉar "ke" kaŭzas pli certon al la frazo, ol "ĉu".

Comment: Kiel vi povas diri, ke unu estas pli klara ol la alia, se ili havas malsaman signifon? Ili ambaŭ estas egale klare, sed je alia signifo, laŭ mi. Oni povas diri, ke en la frazo kun "ke", la demando en la frazo temas pri io, kiu jam havas pli da klareco (ĉar ŝajne jam estas klare al tiu, kiu demandas, ke la alparolato fakte ja amas trian personon), sed la tuta frazo ne estas pli klara.